# Syntax for retrieving the coordinates of point features using GeoPandas

Tags: python, openstreetmap, coordinates, geopandas, osmnx

I have two point shapefiles (with just one point each, let's call them 'Origin' and 'Destination'). I need to find the shortest path between them over a street network extracted using OSMnx from OpenStreetMap. For this, the points' coordinates are needed. First, I have each file read using GeoPandas as follows:

```
import geopandas as gpd
origin_fp = "C:/Users/User Name/Python_experiment/Origin.shp"
destination_fp = "C:/Users/User Name/Python_experiment/Destination.shp"
origin = gpd.read_file(origin_fp)
destination = gpd.read_file(destination_fp)
```

Once this is done, what is the syntax for extracting the coordinates of each feature in the shapefile?

They already have the same coordinate system to which I will project my graph.

Must the shapefiles have attributes for latitude and longitude?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the format of the coordinates you want

```
import geopandas as gpd
df = gpd.read_file("points.shp")
df.head(3)
   FID      geometry
0   0   POINT (-0.18411 0.47266)
1   1   POINT (0.16016 0.34106)
2   2   POINT (-0.46957 0.39932)
df['lon']  = df.geometry.x
df['lat']  = df.geometry.y
df['coords'] = df.geometry.apply(lambda p: list(p.coords)[0])
df.head(3)
   FID  geometry                       lon         lat              coords
0   0   POINT (-0.18411 0.47266)    -0.184108   0.472664    (-0.18410841450105575, 0.47266361459480355)
1   1   POINT (0.16016 0.34106)      0.160162   0.341056    (0.16016249583069841, 0.34105550781849137)
2   2   POINT (-0.46957 0.39932)    -0.469574   0.399324    (-0.4695739603914672, 0.39932386352712257)
```

Comment: So far, df.geometry.x and df.geometry.y seems to work for retrieving the coordinates. When I have resolved other issues that have arisen with my script, I'll know for sure.

Comment: The geometry is a   [shapely geomettry](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#points) therefore df.geometry.x and df.geometry.y is correct.